# is there a way to get a value from json as a variable in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-sound

I am trying to create an app in react native. I have information stored in a database. I use php to get the information for the database using a query.

I then use fetch to get the information and I am able to get the information and display it as text. I would like to have the data as a variable so that I can use it with react-native sound.

Here is my react native code

```js
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          playState:'paused', //playing, paused
          playSeconds:0,
          duration:0,
          FileUrlHolder: ''
      }
      this.sliderEditing = false;
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      fetch('http://f10f7e2e.ngrok.io/Filter.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
       
            // Getting the id.
            id: this.props.navigation.state.params.FlatListClickItemHolder
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
           FileUrlHolder: responseJson[0].FileUrl
           
    });
      
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

  componentWillUnmount(){
 
  play = async () => {
      if(this.sound){
          this.sound.play(this.playComplete);
          this.setState({playState:'playing'});
      }else{
          
        const filepath = this.state.FileUrlHolder;
        console.log('[Play]', filepath);
        //Alert.alert('id ' + filepath);

          this.sound = new Sound(filepath, (error) => {
              if (error) {
                  console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
                  Alert.alert('Notice', 'audio file error. (Error code : 1)');
                  this.setState({playState:'paused'});
              }else{
                  this.setState({playState:'playing', duration:this.sound.getDuration()});
                  this.sound.play(this.playComplete);
              }
          });    
      }
  }
```

My json looks like

```js
[{"FileUrl":"John_30th_sept_2018.mp3"}]
```

Comment: You can turn json string to an object using `JSON.parse("YOUR JSON STRING")`

Comment: How would this work?

Comment: Something like: `.then((responseJson) => { let jsonObj = JSON.parse(responseJson); this.setState({ FileUrlHolder: jsonObj[0].FileUrl }); })`

Comment: this causes an error, SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"

Comment: Looks like `responseJson` is an object. Do `console.log(typeof responseJson[0])` if it's a `string` the JSON.parse that. I'm not sure if I have understood your question well.

Comment: it displays object

Comment: You might be calling `this.play()` before `fetch` is resolved.

Comment: I will have a look at this

Answer (score 1):

When you do `response.json()`, you get back an object that was created using the body of the response. In your case this object will be an array containing an object with a `FileUrl` property. You don't need to `JSON.parse()` it because it has already been parsed into an object, this is why you get an error. Your code should work, what exactly is the problem? Are you certain your backend is returning the correct data?

Comment: yes I have checked my backend and am getting back the right information, I seem to only be able to use the information I get back as texted and not a variable

Comment: i think this might be the line that is causing the problem const filepath = this.state.FileUrlHolder; as when I try to console.log the filepath nothing is printed to the console